# Parallelization in R: %dopar% vs %do%. Why using a single core yields to better performance?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm experiencing a weird behaviour in my computer when distributing processes among its cores using doMC and foreach. Does someone knows why using single core I got better performance than using 2 cores? As you can see, processing the same code without register any core (which supposedly use only 1 core) yields to a much more time-efficiency processing. While %do% seems to perform better than %dopar%, registering 2 cores out of 4 yield to more time consuming.

```
require(foreach)
require(doMC)
# 1-core
> system.time(m <- foreach(i=1:100) %dopar% 
+ matrix(rnorm(1000*1000), ncol=5000) )
   user  system elapsed 
  9.285   1.895  11.083 
> system.time(m <- foreach(i=1:100) %do% 
+ matrix(rnorm(1000*1000), ncol=5000) )
   user  system elapsed 
  9.139   1.879  10.979 

# 2-core
> registerDoMC(cores=2)
> system.time(m <- foreach(i=1:100) %dopar% 
+ matrix(rnorm(1000*1000), ncol=5000) )
   user  system elapsed 
  3.322   3.737 132.027
> system.time(m <- foreach(i=1:100) %do% 
+ matrix(rnorm(1000*1000), ncol=5000) )
   user  system elapsed 
  9.744   2.054  11.740
```

Using 4 cores in few trials yield to very different outcomes:

```
> registerDoMC(cores=4)
> system.time(m <- foreach(i=1:100) %dopar% 
{ matrix(rnorm(1000*1000), ncol=5000) } )
   user  system elapsed 
 11.522   4.082  24.444 
> system.time(m <- foreach(i=1:100) %dopar% 
{ matrix(rnorm(1000*1000), ncol=5000) } )
   user  system elapsed 
 21.388   6.299  25.437 
> system.time(m <- foreach(i=1:100) %dopar% 
{ matrix(rnorm(1000*1000), ncol=5000) } )
   user  system elapsed 
 17.439   5.250   9.300 
> system.time(m <- foreach(i=1:100) %dopar% 
{ matrix(rnorm(1000*1000), ncol=5000) } )
   user  system elapsed 
 17.480   5.264   9.170
```

Comment: 1. Producing a single matrix is not (in general) done in parallel unless you define how it is to be done, and you have not.  You should expect worse results when using more than one core.  2. Does `registerDoMC` affect `%do%`?  The results are similar.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: Please `%do%` check the documentation :-)

Comment: Unless I am reading the output wrong, I am not seeing _"much more time-efficiency processing"_,  it looks like a negligble difference of  barely 1.5%

Comment: @RicardoSaporta note the "elapsed" value for the 2-core `%dopar%` case.

Comment: Sure registerDoMC doesn't affect %do%, I plug results in both syntaxes for comparison purpose. The puzzle, as I did mentioned, is the big difference using 1 to 2 cores, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It absolutely does make sense.  You are asking two cores to update one object, which is programming a series of cache misses.  It is much faster to run *this* code on one core, as you have seen.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but try to replicate the code using 3, 4, 6 cores. You will see the time dropping. Why does so?

Comment: @user792000 Multicore programming is a complex topic.  One core means no locking, but two or more cores is the same number of locks and the same number of contentions.  This is a very contrived problem, and one that is not suited to a parallel solution.  In particular, it is not demonstrating any deficiency in the R parallel code.  (This comment should not be construed to imply that there are no defects in the R parallel code.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the parallel package slower than just using apply?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614306/why-is-the-parallel-package-slower-than-just-using-apply)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the combination of results that eats all the processing time. These are the timings on my machine for the `cores=2` scenario if no results are returned. It's essentially the same code, only the created matrices are discarded instead of being returned:

```
> system.time(m <- foreach(i=1:100) %do% 
+ { matrix(rnorm(1000*1000), ncol=5000); NULL } )
   user  system elapsed 
 13.793   0.376  14.197 
> system.time(m <- foreach(i=1:100) %dopar% 
+ { matrix(rnorm(1000*1000), ncol=5000); NULL } )
   user  system elapsed 
  8.057   5.236   9.970
```

Still not optimal, but at least the parallel version is now faster.

This is from documentation of `doMC`:

> The `doMC` package provides a parallel backend for the
>        `foreach`/`%dopar%` function using the multicore functionality of the
>        `parallel` package.

Now, `parallel` uses a `fork` mechanism to spawn identical copies of the R process. Collecting results from separate processes is an expensive task, and this is what you see in your time measurements.

Comment: Yeah, you have the point. My code was wrong by not distributing the processes. Now, the behaviour is as I expected. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: @user792000: Erm, no. The processes were distributed in your code, too. The only difference is that your code *returns* the matrices it generates, my code discards them.

Comment: It is really weird. Using 4 cores in few trials yield to very different outcomes:

Comment: @krlmlr - so you gain efficiency by distributing the task, but incur an overhead by collecting the results returned by the distributed task?

Comment: Yes, but the overhead also includes copying data to the nodes, scheduling tasks, and maybe something I still forget :).

Comment: @thelatemail: Basically yes, see also Paul's comment. In our case, collecting those huge matrices has the biggest impact.