# Permute matrix columns in parallel with R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, parallel-processing, permutation

I am trying to permute a matrix by columns using R.
However, it is taking ages (the matrix is 68k x 32k integers).

I would like to do it in parallel (since each column is permuted independently). How can I achieve it? It should be something related to embarrassingly parallel for in R but I didn't find a solution.

Currently, my function is the following:

```
permMTX <- function(x) {
    nr <- nrow(x)
    nc <- ncol(x)
    # I'd like to parallelize this for, since each
    # column can be permuted independently
    for (i in 1:nc) {
        x[,i] <- x[sample(nr),i]
    }
    x
}
```

Comment: Is `x` really meant to be a `matrix`? You named the function `permDF`, so I just wanted to make sure it's not a `data.frame`

Comment: Yep, I'll correct the name of the function. Thanks.

Comment: Different take: After doing `x_p <- permMTX(x)` what calculations/operations are you going do on `x_p`?

Comment: @HenrikB a lot of operations, actually - mainly PCA I'd say, why?

Comment: Each time you permute, you create a new 8 GiB matrix. If you permute B times and B is large, that's a lot of memory allocations (and deallocation work for the garbage collector). If you calculate a summary statistics at the end, sometimes it's possible to rewrite the suite of operations ("postpone permutation") so that you can avoid creating B matrices.  It's not simple, not obvious, but is some cases it's possible.

Comment: More to think abount: To make sure you get truly random samples when doing parallel processing, you have to utilize parallel-safe random number generation (RNG). R provides `RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")` and `parallel::nextRNGStream` etc. for this. Unfortunately, that will introduce additional overhead to whatever overhead you have from the parallel orchestration itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

First, I'd make use of vectorization, which should make it more efficient.

```
permMTX = function(x) apply(x, 2L, sample)
```

Then we can use library `parallel` to parallelize that function:

```
library(parallel)

parPermMTX = function(x, cluster) parApply(cl = cluster, X = x, MARGIN = 2L, FUN = sample)
```

---

## Usage

With `parallel` you have to register a cluster before usage. Here's an example:

```
cl = makeCluster(detectCores(logical = FALSE))
parPermMTX(diag(10), cl)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    1    0    0    1    1
#[5,]    0    0    1    0    0
```

The way `parallel` works (spawning multiple R processes) you have to assure that you have enough memory to fit multiple copies of your data as well.

I think it's recommended to export the data to the processes as well, you can do that simply calling

```
clusterExport(cl, varlist = "exampleData")
```

**While it does run in parallel on my end, it's not faster at all than simply employing `apply`, but I couldn't test with data at the same scale as yours, so I can't be sure it'll work.**

This is due to the fact `sample` is heavily optimized already, so the overhead of spawning processes is bigger than simply calling `sample`. See [Why is the parallel package slower than just using apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614306/why-is-the-parallel-package-slower-than-just-using-apply)

On my system, sampling 68E3 integers 32E3 times takes roughly 40 seconds:

```
microbenchmark(sample(68E3), times = 32E3)
#Unit: milliseconds
#          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# sample(68000) 1.132273 1.192923 1.290838 1.227912 1.286229 7.880191 32000
```

Perhaps you're running out of memory, and using the hard disk cache, which is really slow.

---

## 2nd Solution

So, what if we tried to allocate as many calls to `sample` sequentially to a single process? This is what I tried here:

```
parPermMTX2 = function(x, cluster) do.call(cbind, parLapply(cl = cluster, X = list(x[,seq(floor(ncol(x)/2))], x[,floor(ncol(x)/2)+seq(ceiling(ncol(x)/2))]), fun = permMTX))
```

We divide `x` into two halves, then call `permMTX` in each, then recombine with `cbind`.

Sadly, neither this way I could achieve better performance. So, while I answered your question, I'm not sure it's any help at all.

Comment: Very interesting answer. I think I am going to test with vectorized function if my memory fails to keep the copies of the matrix. Thanks

Comment: @gc5 If you found another answer more useful than mine you can unaccept mine and accept theirs, just letting you know :)

Comment: In this case I used your suggestion since it's the simplest and reasonably fast. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of package **bigstatsr**.

You can use shared memory (matrices stored on disk) and do this:

```
# devtools::install_github("privefl/bigstatsr")
library(bigstatsr)

# matrix on disk
mat <- FBM(68e3, 32e2, backingfile = "test")
# inialize with 1:nrow(mat) for each column
system.time(
  big_apply(mat, a.FUN = function(X, ind) {
    print(min(ind))
    X[, ind] <- rep(rows_along(X), length(ind))
    NULL
  }, a.combine = 'c')
) # 15 sec

# permute each column, in parallel
system.time(
  big_apply(mat, a.FUN = function(X, ind) {
    print(min(ind))
    X[, ind] <- apply(X[, ind], 2, sample)
    NULL
  }, a.combine = 'c', ncores = nb_cores())
) # 27 sec
```

This takes 27 secs on a tenth of the data and 378 sec on the whole dataset (on a laptop computer with only 2 physical cores and 8GB of RAM).

Comment: Sound really cool, I'll have to try this. Just one thing, though, you're the author of the package right? It's common etiquette to include a statement or disclaimer saying that, like referring to the package as _"my package"_ or simply writing _"(which is my creation)"_, or anything else to the same effect. No big deal though, just though I'd let you know that. [It's better to disclose such information to avoid being mistook for spam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285851/user-promoting-his-software-in-relevant-questions-without-disclosure).

Comment: Nice solution. In this case I don't need shared memory but this approach is really useful. Thanks